# Popup menu on custom view in Eclipse Plug-In (Kepler)

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to provide a static popup menu for a custom view in Eclipse Kepler? Creating a dynamic one is easy, but I would like to be able to define the commands in the plugin.xml file as for the Project Explorer.
Looking at my custom view with the Eclipse Spy I see no active menu contribution identifiers. How can I define one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view part set up the context menu like this:

```
MenuManager contextMenu = new MenuManager();
contextMenu.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);

Control control = viewer.getControl();
Menu menu = contextMenu.createContextMenu(control);
control.setMenu(menu);

getSite().registerContextMenu(contextMenu, viewer);
```

The `registerContextMenu` call makes the menu available to the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point so you can define menu items like this:

```
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:your view id here">
         ... you menu items ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to upvote your answer, though it works! With the registerContextMenu() I was able to access the extension point.